# Is there a way to use Angular to display content onclick of a button?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I want to show a list of articles on my page. First displaying everything, but then if a user clicks a button it would only just show articles relevant to the button clicked. This means it would look at the 'grape' in the array and if it is red, show red wines from the list. It would be good to have a button to show all that would default back to the initial view. Any help welcome.

```
<button>Show ALL Articles<button>
<button ng-click="filter('red')">Show me articles with red wines<button>
<button ng-click="filter('white')">Show me articles with white wines<button>
<button ng-click="filter('rose')">Show me articles with rose wines<button>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in wineListings | filter: filter">
        <h2>{{item.country}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.grape}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$scope.wineListings = [
    {
        country:"France",
        grape:"red"
    },
    {
        country:"Spain",
        grape:"red"
    },
    {
        country:"Italy",
        grape:"white"
    },    
    {
        country:"USA",
        grape:"rose"
    }
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried the above (Just edited my original code to include my attempt)

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve what you need just by having an additional variable in your scope which is passed as a parameter to `| filter` via Angular's built-in object matching syntax, specifically:

```
wineListings | filter: { grape: selected }
```

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope) {
$scope.wineListings = [
    {
        country:"France",
        grape:"red"
    },
    {
        country:"Spain",
        grape:"red"
    },
    {
        country:"Italy",
        grape:"white"
    },    
    {
        country:"USA",
        grape:"rose"
    }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<button ng-click="selected=''">Show me all wines</button>
<button ng-click="selected='red'">Show me red wines</button>
<button ng-click="selected='white'">Show me white wines</button>
<button ng-click="selected='rose'">Show me rose wines</button>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in wineListings | filter : { grape: selected }">
        <h2>{{item.country}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.grape}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello @Alnitak .. Thanks but I noticed that the Show me red wines button doesn't always work correctly as it shows nothing, then shows all wines. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: @Al-76 you dont have to post another answer derived from my answer i think

Comment: @Al-76 I can't replicate that on my Chrome browser on macOS.

Comment: @Sajeetharan if that comment was directed at me, please note that although I did indeed re-use your snippet for efficiency, the method of operation is completely different (and more closely matches the OP's code).

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function by passing the parameter with the button option and apply the logic using array.filter on the controller as follows,

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.selectedColor;
$scope.wineListings = [
    {
        country:"France",
        grape:"red"
    },
    {
        country:"Spain",
        grape:"red"
    },
    {
        country:"Italy",
        grape:"white"
    },    
    {
        country:"USA",
        grape:"rose"
    }
];
$scope.fill = function(input){
      return input =='all'? $scope.wineListings: $scope.wineListings.filter(t=>t.grape ===input);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<button ng-click="selectedColor='all'">Show me all wines</button>
<button ng-click="selectedColor='red'">Show me red wines</button>
<button ng-click="selectedColor='white'">Show me white wines</button>
<button ng-click="selectedColor='rose'">Show me rose wines</button>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in fill(selectedColor)">
        <h2>{{item.country}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.grape}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: you're over-writing the actual contents of `$scope.wineListings` on each press?   That can't be right...

Comment: also massive DRY principle violations combined with completely unnecessary hard-coded branches that are data specific.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for the headsup, i have improved the answer

Comment: @Sajeetharan There seems to be a bug but this is almost working. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Omg crazy guys downvotig

Answer (score 0):

you can use function on click the button that takes the color that you want like this

```
   <button value="Show me white wines" onClick="list('white')">
```

and this function list can filter your array according to the color you send in the parameter like this

```
public list(String color){
  return this.wineListings.filter(wine => wine.grape === color);
}
```

and list the array after filtration